# Java regex to find delimiters with release character

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get a similar result \ has in Java String literals. If there are two of them, it's a \, otherwise it "escapes" whatever follows. So if there is a delimiter that follows a single release char, it doesn't count. But two release chars resolve to a release char literal, so then the following delimiter should be considered a delimiter. So, if an odd number of release chars precede a delimiter, it's ignored. For 0 or an even number it's a delimiter. So, in the code example below:

```
?: <- : is not a delimiter
??: <- : is a delimiter
???: <- : is not a delimiter
????: <- : is a delimiter
```

Here's sample code showing what doesn't work.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestPattern
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\?\\?)*[^\\?]\\:").matcher("a??:b:c");
        m.find(0);
        System.out.println(m.end());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you want `(\\?\\?)+:`

Comment: No. If you read the text hopefully you can see what I'm trying to do. There might not be any ? at all but I still need to match the delimiter. I need to match unescaped delimiters.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. Could you post some example and few results that will show what you are trying to match/find and what you want to omit? Also what is relationship between `?` and `:`? What is your delimiter? If delimiter is set of even number of question marks and colon then maybe try `(\\?\\?)*:` without `[^\\?]` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that just be reversing the regex it works. Putting the "don't match a ?" first, and then the "any even number of ?'s" seems to do the trick:

`[^?](\\?\\?)*:`

Answer (score 1):

The following should work

```
\b(\?{2})*:
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex means:

Zero or more '??'

```
(\\?\\?)*
```

Followed by not '?'

```
[^\\?]
```

Ending in ':'

```
\\:
```

So, your last match is the last colon. That's why the result offset is 6.

You could change for:

```
final Matcher m = Pattern.compile("((\\?){2})+").matcher("a??:b:????:c");
while (m.find()){
    //outputs 1 and 6, places 
    //you would have to start
    //scaping...
    System.out.println(m.start()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `*` means there can be zero of that group. So that capturing group can be the empty string. `[^\\?]` can be any character that isn't a `?`, as `?` is not a special character inside a character class. The `\` is ignored.

Therefore, `b:` (with an empty string preceding it) matches, and the second colon is your last (and, in this case, first) match.

I think you simply want `"(\\?\\?)*\\?:"`.